# How to count pymongo aggregation cursor without iterating

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I want to get the total number of records in an aggregate cursor in pymongo version 3.0+. Is there any way to get total count without iterating over the cursor?

```
cursor = db.collection.aggregate([{"$match": options},{"$group": {"_id": groupby,"count": {"$sum":1}}} ])
cursorlist = [c for c in cursor]
print len(cursorlist)
```

Is there any way to skip the above iteration?

Comment: In your above code len(list(cursor)) will give you the count of records returned. 2nd line is not needed therefore.

Comment: Thanks @Sarath this will be useful if i don't want to update my aggregation query.

Answer (score 8):

You could add another group pipeline where you specify an `_id` value of `None` to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole, this is where you can get the total count, as well as the original grouped counts, albeit in an accumulated array:

```
>>> pipeline = [
...     {"$match": options},
...     {"$group": {"_id": groupby, "count": {"$sum":1}}},
...     {"$group": {"_id": None, "total": {"$sum": 1}, "details":{"$push":{"groupby": "$_id", "count": "$count"}}}}
... ]
>>> list(db.collection.aggregate(pipeline))
```

Comment: This worked. Only minor change, Python have to use None and not null thanks!

Comment: @jadhavmahendra7 Good catch! I've updated my answer to reflect this, cheers :)